# Why can I find this text box element in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I cant get my selenium code to find this element in a page, it appears after ive used code to click a button on a page which opens up a form under the button.

Im looking to try get it to click on this input text box

```
<input id="number" class="iField" type="text" name="number">
```

My code

```
driver1.implicitly_wait(10)
driver1.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR("input#number")))
button = driver1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="number"]')
```

Website code

```
<form id="form" action="https://secureacceptance.cybersource.com/silent/embedded" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<div class="form-row">
                    <div class="left-col">
                        <label>No: </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-col">
                        <input id="number" class="iField" type="text" name="number">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I've tried using Xpath, name Etc,  but keep getting the unable to locate element.

Edit
ive also tried this

```
num = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH("//*[@id='number']")))
num.click()
```

But get this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\OneDrive\coding\code.py", line 68, in 
num = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH("//*[@id='number']")))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Which text do you want to find?

Comment: I want to find the `<input id="number" class="iField" type="text" name="number">`

Comment: You did not type the text)

Comment: Ok, Got it. I'll add the answer

Comment: What error are you getting? If you are getting timeout error please check the element must be inside an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#number")))
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#number")
element.click()
```

You have id, so you can also use `find_element_by_id` instead of `find_element_by_css_selector`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("number")
element.click()
```

Please note that I am waiting till this element becomes actually clickable.

Also, I don't understand why you are using `driver1`. Use `driver` for all elements.

**Try 2**
The answer is easier than I thought. You are messing up with ()

```
num = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='number']")))
```

**Try 3** (more detailed)

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='number']")))
```

Check here how to use explicit waits https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: Its throwing the error select by is not defined

Comment: Change it to By

Comment: I just import it as SelectBy

Comment: Changed it to driver.

however getting this error
File "c:\Users\OneDrive\coding\code.py", line 69, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR("#number")))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: 1min, I'll add this import

Comment: Still getting 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\danin\OneDrive\coding\code.py", line 69, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR("#number")))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: I think the problem is how you declare driver1. Declare is as you did previously. It is selenium object. It is recognized as string because you incorrectly declare it. Looks like  this is the issue. Your xpath is correct

Comment: Don't create driver1. Use previously declared driver

Comment: I hope this helps

Comment: I've set it all back to driver, I originally changed this because i thought it would clash and throw an error up.

`driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\danin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\geckodriver.exe")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230679/discussion-between-vitaliis-and-dan-brittle).

Comment: Check try2. I think this is the issue

Comment: should there be a bracket or not ?
`((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='number']")))` 
or
`((By.XPATH("//*[@id='number']")))`

Comment: Check the bottom of the answer. Try 2.

Comment: Still not working same error i believe its something to do with the XPATH, CSS_SELECTOR,ID being a string

Comment: Between above options the first is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

num = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='number']")))
```

your webdriverwait syntax is incorrect use the above one , you should not call By.xpath but pass it as a tuple to the EC

also do not use implicit wait ,

Comment: Im getting this error now
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\OneDrive\coding\code.py", line 69, in <module>
    num = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"#id='number")))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: How would i pass it as a tuple?

Comment: Ya now it's correct try using presence of , instead of visibility for expected condition

Comment: Still getting the timeout exception error not sure why, is it because i need to wait for the java script or jquery to finish loading idk

Comment: Yes, do not use implicit wait and explicit wait together. This is right.

Comment: do you have link to the website ?